# How do I apply an Indian language system-wide?

Tags: 12.04, system, language-support, internationalization

I want to add Indian languages system wide.I see on English and Chinese options .I also updated font cache. The image says it all.
First is the gnome tweak tool and second the font viewer.
How do i render them and apply system wide... ? 
(I am not speaking of keyboard layout. I want the windows and its contents to be in Indian language.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to add Indian languages system wide.

- Here's how. Open Language Support from within Software Settings.

  [image]
- Click Install/Remove Languages and select the Indian language(s) you want to install, click Apply Changes.

  [image]
- Let the process finish.

  [image]
- Now you have to click and drag the languages you want (in order of preference) to the *top of the Language for Menus and Windows box*. It will replace the language that is highlighted in orange and push it down:

  [image]
- Click on "Apply System Wide" and set an appropriate keyboard input method if you need one.
- Logout and then login.
- It works!:

  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Only one thing needs to be appended in the ablove method before step 4 i.e dragging the language on top is : You need to reinstall package called 'locales' from terminal,synaptic or software centre.
(without the single quotes.)

Comment: I did a Ubuntu server 12.04 installation, chosing spanish as primary language, because I wanted to have RAID 1 support, and server installer makes it easier, though I'm using the installation as desktop. After that I installed the meta package `ubuntu-desktop` and the desktop had mixed languages messages. Thanks to these posts, I installed all the necesary packages and the problem was solved. If there's some Ubuntu server's maintainer reading, you might want to add a trigger or the dependencies to the meta package to install the necessary  internalization packages.